# Normalizer not removing accents

Tags: kotlin, internationalization

I'm using `Normalizer` followed by a regex to remove accents, but I'm getting back the same string with the accents still there.

```kotlin
import java.text.*

const val INPUT = "áéíóůø"
fun main() {
    println(Normalizer.normalize(INPUT, Normalizer.Form.NFC).replace("[\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}]+", ""))
    println(Normalizer.normalize(INPUT, Normalizer.Form.NFD).replace("[\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}]+", ""))
    println(Normalizer.normalize(INPUT, Normalizer.Form.NFKC).replace("[\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}]+", ""))
    println(Normalizer.normalize(INPUT, Normalizer.Form.NFKD).replace("[\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}]+", ""))
}
```

Output:

> áéíóůø
>
> áéíóůø
>
> áéíóůø
>
> áéíóůø

Kotlin playground: https://pl.kotl.in/62l6rUEUm

I've read a dozen questions here that say the way to strip accent marks in Java/Kotlin is to use `java.text.Normalizer` plus some minor variation of the above regular expression (sometimes without square brackets, sometimes without the plus). Even Apache Common's `stripAccent` function uses `Normalizer` for its implementation (but apparently handles to special characters too).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not make `"[\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}]+"` a `Regex`.

```
println(
    Normalizer.normalize(INPUT, Normalizer.Form.NFD)
        .replace("[\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}]+".toRegex(), "")
)
```

This produces:

```
aeiouø
```

Notice that the stroke in `ø` is not a diacritic mark. It can be decomposed to neither

- "o" and U+0338 COMBINING LONG SOLIDUS OVERLAY, or;
- "o" and U+0337 COMBINING SHORT SOLIDUS OVERLAY

You can see that these three all look a bit different: o̸øo̷

Also notice that there are two more blocks in Unicode that contains combining diacritics, called "[Combining Diacritical Marks Extended](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_Diacritical_Marks_Extended)" and "[Combining Diacritical Marks Supplement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_Diacritical_Marks_Supplement)". Consider including those in your regex too.